# How to use restsharp to download file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, httpclient, restsharp

I have a URL  (URL for the live feed from client) which when I hit in browser returns the xml response . I have saved this in text file it`s size is 8 MB.

now my problem is that I need to save this response in xml file on server`s drive. from there I will insert this in database. and request needs to be made using code using http-client or rest-sharp library of c# .net 4.5

I am unsure what should I do for above case. can any body suggest me something

Answer (score 53, accepted):

With RestSharp, it's right there in the [readme](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/README.md):

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
client.DownloadData(request).SaveAs(path);
```

With `HttpClient`, it's a bit more involved. Have a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/17/downloading-a-google-map-to-local-file.aspx).

Another option is [Flurl.Http](https://flurl.io/docs/fluent-http/) (disclaimer: I'm the author). It uses `HttpClient` under the hood and provides a fluent interface and lots of convenient helper methods, including:

```
await "http://example.com".DownloadFileAsync(folderPath, "foo.xml");
```

Get it on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/).

Comment: The method `SaveAs` was removed? I can't use it.
Probably I have to use `File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, bytesArray);`

Comment: @JCarlos : The `SaveAs` method is still there. It's in the `RestSharp.Extensions` namespace, `MiscExtensions` class.

Comment: Updated ReadMd Link: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Too bad `DownloadData` doesn't have an async version

Answer (score 28):

It seems SaveAs was discontinued. You can try this

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com")    
byte[] response = client.DownloadData(request);
File.WriteAllBytes(SAVE_PATH, response);
```

Comment: See comment in above answer.

Comment: SaveAs is still there, you have to add a using statement: `using RestSharp.Extensions;`

Comment: MiscExtensions.SaveAs has been marked obsolete in newer versions.

Answer (score 19):

In case you want async version

```
var request = new RestRequest("/resource/5", Method.GET);
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    throw new Exception($"Unable to download file");
response.RawBytes.SaveAs(path);
```

Comment: Where is request defined?

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt, I updated answer with Request initialization

Comment: "'MiscExtensions.SaveAs(byte[], string)' is obsolete: 'This method will be removed soon. If you use it, please copy the code to your project."

Comment: FYI `ExecuteTaskAsync` is also obsolete.

Answer (score 7):

Don't keep the file in memory while reading. Write it directly to the disk.

```
var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
using var writer = File.OpenWrite(tempFile);

var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
var request = new RestRequest("Assets/LargeFile.7z");
request.ResponseWriter = responseStream =>
{
    using (responseStream)
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(writer);
    }
};
var response = client.DownloadData(request);
```

Copied from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59720610/179017.

Answer (score 4):

Add following NuGet package into the current system

> dotnet add package RestSharp

**Using Bearer Authentication**

```
// Download file from 3rd party API
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Download([FromQuery] string fileUri)
{
  // Using rest sharp 
  RestClient client = new RestClient(fileUri);
  client.ClearHandlers();
  client.AddHandler("*", () => { return new JsonDeserializer(); });
  RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
  request.AddParameter("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer " + accessToken), 
  ParameterType.HttpHeader);
  IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
  if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
  {
    // Read bytes
    byte[] fileBytes = response.RawBytes;
    var headervalue = response.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Content-Disposition")?.Value;
    string contentDispositionString = Convert.ToString(headervalue);
    ContentDisposition contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(contentDispositionString);
    string fileName = contentDisposition.FileName;
    // you can write a own logic for download file on SFTP,Local local system location
    //
    // If you to return file object then you can use below code
    return File(fileBytes, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
  }
}
```

**Using Basic Authentication**

```
// Download file from 3rd party API
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Download([FromQuery] string fileUri)
{ 
  RestClient client = new RestClient(fileUri)
    {
       Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("your user name", "your password")
    };
  client.ClearHandlers();
  client.AddHandler("*", () => { return new JsonDeserializer(); });
  RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);  
  IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
  if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
  {
    // Read bytes
    byte[] fileBytes = response.RawBytes;
    var headervalue = response.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Content-Disposition")?.Value;
    string contentDispositionString = Convert.ToString(headervalue);
    ContentDisposition contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(contentDispositionString);
    string fileName = contentDisposition.FileName;
    // you can write a own logic for download file on SFTP,Local local system location
    //
    // If you to return file object then you can use below code
    return File(fileBytes, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect logic for save file from the response using Bearer Authentication. Thanks for saving a time.

Comment: Needs a bunch of extra imports, usage of these functions would be good as well, and IDE says that not all code paths return a value