# C# - RestSharp - GET - Assert image png

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, automation, restsharp

I have created a API tests using RestSharp for test automation

I want to create a test where I Assert that and I get the correct image from a GET request in the response

```
client = new RestClient(ConfigurationHelper.GetValue("BaseURL"));
client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator((Domain + User), Password);
request = new RestRequest(EndPoint, Method.GET);
IRestResponse restResponse = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
var response = restResponse.Content;
```

However when I set a breakpoint at the last line, the response content is displayed as a string

[image]

How can I assert this correctly? Or is there a better way to send the GET request and assert the response as an image

Comment: Instead of ExecuteAsync use DownloadData to get bytes of the file. You can assert equality of the generated hash of the file then.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1):

This is answear [How to use restsharp to download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123291/how-to-use-restsharp-to-download-file) on your question.

But I will modify your test a little bit:

1. Create request to download image
2. You get array of image bytes

```
request = new RestRequest(EndPoint, Method.GET);
byte[] restResponse = client.DownloadData(request);
```

3. And check image type [Determine file type of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869/determine-file-type-of-an-image/12451102#12451102)
4. Also, you can check length of image - if the image is static in your test.