# Asp.Net MVC view how to add script src from backend?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC view where I am using Yandex external API for address search.

This is the script I have to add in order to use the Yandex services.

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=xxxxxxxxxx&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">
```

Is there a way to read this script src from the backend instead of directly using it in the View, as it contains the api key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use restsharp to download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123291/how-to-use-restsharp-to-download-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a server side method to 'read' the script src file from the ASP.Net server. You would perform an HTTP GET using something like [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0). This is effective if you are retrieving JSON data or some other type of data to process on the server.

However, the C# backend would not process JavaScript instructions. For that you would need a server side JavaScript engine such as Node, or the client's web browser.

Including the JavaScript file in the View will allow the client's JavaScript engine to handle processing. But as you have implied, nothing in the View is hidden from the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Action that loads and returns the script, then reference that Action in your html, eg:

```
<script src='@Url.Action("LoadYandex")'>
```

and

```
public ActionResult LoadYandex() {
    // HttpClient to get the file
    return Content(file, "text/javascript");
}
```

---

**Edit** more detailed Action example, basic "get file from server and return contents".  Look for more detailed SO answers to include error checking etc

```
public async Task<ActionResult> LoadYandex()
{
    var url = "https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=xxxxxxxxxx&lang=ru_RU"; 

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return Content(contents, "text/javascript");
}
```

Comment: With this I am able to get the url content, but I can still see the url with api key in the <script>in the browser when we inspect Elements.

Comment: Then I've not explained it clear enough.  You need to *remove* your existing `<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=xxxxxxxxxx...` and replace it with `<script src='@Url.Action("LoadYandex")'>` which should then look, when *rendered*, like:  `<script src="http://your_server/your_project/controller/LoadYandex">` and nothing else, so there should be no key in the javascript.

Comment: Are you returning the string `"https://api-maps...."` from the Action?  Don't do that, load the script *in the action* and return the content.   I skipped that bit as it wasn't directly related to the principle of loading the script *server-side* then passing it.  **edit** added as *basic* implementation to download the file *server-side* and send the *content* (not the url) back to the client.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m, it works. 
Is there a way to call this action method from .js file as well? I have to use the key again in the .js file.

OR

Is there a way to keep the url "https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=xxxxxxxxxx&lang=ru_RU";  in another .js file and then use it in View ?

Comment: Once you've done `var contents = await ... readasstring...` you can manipulate the string all you like, eg `contents = contents.replace("https://api-maps...", "https://you_server/controller/action")`.  If you need it again, consider a similar replacement.  Essentially, you're creating a proxy server that adds the key at the server level.

Comment: Is there a way to call the **Web API** action method  instead of Controller Action method from .js file and return the javascript content?